# Java Script Pub/Sub pattern passing unique parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, unique, publish-subscribe

Using the publish / subscriber pattern in Java Script, if a publisher publishes an event and that event has 3 subscribers for example, what can be done if one subscriber needs an argument of 'some value' to do it's job and the another subscriber needs and argument of 'some different value' to do it's job etc.?

So 'func1', 'func2', & 'func3' will fire when a button click event is published. Each 'func' needs a unique argument. This button click code is just for example.

```
  let events = {},
      subUid = -1;

  let pubsub = {
      subscribe : function(evt, func, args) {
          if (!events[evt]) {
              events[evt] = [];
          };

          let token = (++subUid).toString();

          events[evt].push({
              token : token,
              func : func
          });

          return token;
      },

      unsubscribe : function(token) {
          for (let m in events) {
              if (events[m]) {

                  for (let i = 0, j = events[m].length; i < j; i++) {
                      if (events[m][i].token === token) {
                          events[m].splice( i, 1 );
                          return token;
                      };
                  };
              };
          };
          return this;
      },

      publish : function(evt, args) {
          if (!events[evt]) {
              throw ''+evt+' doesn\'t exist!';
          };

          const subscribers = events[evt];
          const len = (subscribers) ? subscribers.length : 0;

          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              subscribers[i].func(evt, args); // What to do here??!
          };

          return this;
      }
  };
```

/* ------------------- Implementation -------------------- */

```
  $('#myButton').on('click', this, function(event) {
      let someVal = [2, 3, 4];
      someHandler(someVal);
  });

  const func1 = (evt, someVal)=> {
            let total = someVal * 5;
            console.log(total);
        },
        func2 = (evt, someDifferentVal)=> {
            let total = someDifferentVal * 10;
            console.log(total);
        },
        func3 = (evt, anotherDifferentVal)=> {
            let total = anotherDifferentVal * 15;
            console.log(total);
        };

  let subscription1 = pubsub.subscribe('newEventA', func1),
      subscription2 = pubsub.subscribe('newEventA', func2),
      subscription3 = pubsub.subscribe('newEventA', func3);


  let someHandler = (args)=> {
      pubsub.publish('newEventA', args);
  };
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Post a code snippet or give some sort of an example. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events allow you to decouple the components that fire the events from the components that consume the events.

Having the component the fires the event worry about which consumer needs what, defeats the purpose of events, which suppose to be fire and forget.

Your publisher should pack all the information that it could provide into the argument, and have the consumer figure out and extract the relevant information by themselves.

For example, instead of just sending the `id` in the `publish` command, you might want to send additional parameters and pack them in an object.
e.g.

```
pubsub.publish('newEventA', { id: 1, name: 'someName', ... });
```

Events that need the `id` would know to extract the `id` from the argument, and events that need other fields, would know how to extract them.

Also, your platform might have a library for creating and firing custom events.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Thank you very much areller! I see what you are saying. "Having the component the fires the event worry about which consumer needs what" does defeats the purpose! I kind of suspected that might be the case but I wasn't sure. I will check out the link you provided. I just edited my question to ask how to have the consumer figure out and extract the relevant information by themselves. That is actually the essence of my question. Thank you very much!!